# VB.Net How do I get events handler name?

Tags: vb.net, events, drag-and-drop

I have a question about vb.net events,

I m creating a shortcut tool in vb.net using drag drop, but I need to get event handler name in vb.net, this is my code ;

```
  Dim lcTypeOfToolStrip As Type = GetType(ToolStripButton)
        Dim exFormAsObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(lcTypeOfToolStrip)
        Dim evClick As EventInfo = lcTypeOfToolStrip.GetEvent("Click")
        Dim tDelegate As Type = evClick.EventHandlerType
        Dim miHandler As MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod(argToolStripButton.Name & "_Click", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        Dim lcDel As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(tDelegate, Me, miHandler, True)
        sbAddRemoveEventHandler(argToolStripButton, "Click", lcDel)
```

In this code "argToolStripButton.Name & "_Click"" this code must be dynamic.
I need to get event name that assined to Click event in vb.net.

Comment: You don't mean event name, but method (name) that is handling the event.

Comment: Actually yes :) I want to get the method name that assined to event. For example, -->Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load<-- in this decleration I want to get "frmMain_Load" string, I tried using reflection but I could not do it